Exercise about stability and inequality in ODE.
I am stuck with this exercise.
Let
\begin{equation}
        x''(t) + x(t) = \epsilon \sin(x(t))
\end{equation}
with initial conditions $ x(0) = x_0, \ x'(0) = v_0 $.
1. Write the problem as a first order system and check it has the form $ X'(t) = f_0(X(t)) + \epsilon f(X(t)) $, $ X(t) \in \mathbb{R}^2 $ where $ f_0 $ is globally Lipschitz.
2. Prove that all solutions are defined for $ t \in \mathbb{R} $.
3. Prove that if $ X_0(t) $ is a solution with $ \epsilon = 0 $, then for a given $ T > 0 $
\begin{equation}
    ||X(t) - X_0(t)|| \leq \epsilon T e^{L t}
    , \ \ \ 0 \leq t \leq T
\end{equation}
for some constant $ L > 0 $.
4. Prove that for $ 0 < \epsilon < 1 $, the solutions are periodic around the origin, but for $ \epsilon > 1 $, the origin is an unstable point.
I have problems with third and fourth questions. But to understand what I have tried I need to remark some facts about first and second ones. The answer to the first question (the ODE system) is
\begin{equation}
    x' = v, \ \ v' = -x + \epsilon \sin(x)
\end{equation}
and then calling $ X = (x, v) $ we have
\begin{equation}
    X' = (v, -x) + \epsilon (0, \sin(x))
       = f_0(X) + \epsilon g(X)
\end{equation}
being $ f_0(x, v) = (v, -x) $ and $ g(x, y) = (0, \sin(x)) $.
For the third one, I have written the solutions of the system obtained in 1. as
\begin{equation}
    X(t) = x_0 + \int_0^t f(X(s)) + \epsilon g(X(s)) \ ds
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
    X_0(t) = x_0 + \int_0^t f(X(s)) \ ds
\end{equation}
and then
\begin{equation}
    X(t) - X_0(t) 
    = \int_0^t \epsilon g(X(s)) \ ds
    = \epsilon \left(0, \int_0^t \sin(x(s)) \ ds \right)
\end{equation}
But I am not able to get the inequality I need from here. In fact, I can easily derive some similar inequalities, but not the one from the statement of the exercise.
I have tried linearization on the fourth question, but I am unable to use the typical theorems, because eigenvalues have zero real part.
Important: I should solve this exercise without solving the system or the second order EDO. This is, I should not use the explicit solutions form to derive the answers to the questions.

This system seems to have a first integral $L(x, v) = \tfrac{1}{2}x^2+\tfrac{1}{2}v^2 + \varepsilon\cos(x)$

Set $U(t)=X(t)-X_0(t)$. It is then straightforward to see that
$$
\|U'(t)\|\le\|U(t)\|+\epsilon.
$$
Now apply the Grönwall lemma/theorem.

As $U(0)=0$ it follows via mean value inequality that
$$
\|U(t)\|=\|U(t)-U(0)\|\le\int_0^t\|U'(s)\|\,ds
\le \epsilon t+\int_0^t\|U(s)\|\,ds
$$
Applying the integrating factor $e^{-t}$ with the combined scalar function $$\phi(t)=\epsilon(t+1)+\int_0^t\|U(s)\|\,ds$$ gives
$$
\frac{d}{dt}(-e^{-t}\phi(t))=e^{-t}(\phi(t)-\phi'(t))
=e^{-t}\left(\epsilon t+\int_0^t\|U(s)\|\,ds-\|U(t)\|\right)\ge 0.
$$
Thus
$$
-e^{-t}\phi(t)\ge-\phi(0)=-\epsilon\implies \|U(t)\|\le\phi(t)-\epsilon\le\epsilon (e^t-1)
$$
This is a little stronger than the claim, as $e^t-1\le te^t$.

What version of Gronwall? I know that if $ u'(t) \leq C(t) \cdot u(t) $ then (under certain conditions of regularity) we can conclude $ u(t) \leq u(0) \cdot \int_0^t C(t) \ dt $. But here we don't have a derivative, but the norm of a derivative, $ || U'(t) || $. Tanks for your response.

You could set $u(t)=|U(t)|$ and then explore if $u'(t)\le|U'(t)|$. Or go over the integral equation $|U(t)|\le\int_0^t|U'(s)|,ds\le ϵt + \int_0^t|U(s)|,ds$.
